# CORS policy Issue, when adding withCredentials: true to Axios headers. (JavaScript, React, Express)

Tags: reactjs, express, authentication, axios, jwt

I am trying to build a full-stack application with React in Front-End and Express in Back-end. The problem I currently have is that I am getting the following error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5666/auth/getUsers' from origin                     > 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't    > pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the      > response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The         > credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials > attribute.

after I have added a "withCredentials: true" to axios config to send cookies back to back-end.

I do not know how to solve this problem since it appears only when Credentials mode is set and I have already tried to add a cors middleware to express like app.use(cors({origin: "http://localhost:3000/"})); , I have tried to set origin to "*" and also to let cors options empty. Also I have tried to add a *'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : 'http://localhost:5666/auth/getUsers* Header and also "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true. Normally the cors meddleware had solved this problem but now I do not know what should I do. I have already made research but didn't find any usefull information. So if somebody knows, how to solve that problem, it would be nice if you help me.

here is my code where I am sending the request:

```
`class UserService{

    static async getAll(){
        const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("accessToken")
        return await axios.get<{data: UsersListData, msg: string}>("/auth/getUsers", { withCredentials: true, headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : 'http://localhost:5666/auth/getUsers', "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true, Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`}});
    }
}`
```

here is the code from my express server:

```
const app = express();


//middleware
app.use(cors({origin: "http://localhost:3000"}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
dotenv.config();
app.use("/auth", authRoutes);
```

Is there any solutions to send credentials to the server without setting all this headers or if not, what should I exactly do now to make it work?

What did I try:

sending a request to express server from React app via axios, including credentials (cookie with refresh token). I expect the server to receive the request, but an error with cors-policy appears...

Thank You!